# Issue loading XML on flash CS6 AS3 - not showing the content of the document

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, xml-parsing, flash-cs6

I'm just trying to load a XML file to my Flash project. I think it's loading the file because it's not giving me any errors but when i try to use the information from the XML file the page is empty. I don't know why, I don't know where i am wrong. Hope you can help me.
Here is the code:

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLLoader;


//zadavame dva masiva za vyprosi i otgovori
var questions:Array = new Array();
var tt:Array = new Array();
var answers:Array = new Array();
var toch:Array = new Array();


function loadingXML(e:Event):void {
    var myxml = new XML(e.target.data);
    var loop = myxml.ques.length();
    for (var i = 0; i < loop; i++) {
        questions[i] = myxml.ques[i].q1;
        answers[i] = [myxml.ques[i].op1,myxml.ques[i].op2,myxml.ques[i].op3];
        tt[i] = myxml.ques[i].typ;
        toch[i] = myxml.ques[i].tochki;
    }
}


test1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, test1_click);
test2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, test2_click);

function test1_click(event:MouseEvent):void{    
     var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.load(new URLRequest("QPTest_Version1.xml"));
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadingXML);

     gotoAndPlay(3);
}

function test2_click(event:MouseEvent):void{    
     var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.load(new URLRequest("QPTest_Version2.xml"));
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadingXML);

     gotoAndPlay(4);
}
```

If you need I can send you the other part of the code where i am using the information from the XML but i think the mistake is somewhere in this part of the code.
I am sorry if my question is simple but i can't find an answer. Thank you.

Comment: does `trace(e.target.data)` show anything? Also, post a sample of your XML

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer of my problem :) Because i am using part of already written script from my friend i didn't know exactly what she is using so i really didn't notice that she have dynamic text boxes and she use them to show the information from the XML file. Now i know and i fixed the problem. Sorry for the stuped question and everything but was my first time using XML files in flash.